# How to prove there exist a rational which is less than some rational in agda?

Tags: agda

I want to proof that there exist an rational which is less than some rational. for example..

```
v : ℚ
v = + 1 ÷ 2

thm : (Σ[ x ∈ ℚ ] (x Data.Rational.≤ v))
thm = ?
```

What to write in second line??

And what is the meaning of x ∈ ℚ, will it give an element of ℚ or what.

And where is it defined over Set as i found this in Stream and there it defined over stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to follow the definitions.

First of all, we take a look at what the `Σ` part of `Σ[ x ∈ ℚ ] x ≤ v` is. This data type is defined in the module `Data.Product` simply as `Σ`. The whole thing with `∈` is just a *syntactic sugar*, as can be seen from the following line:

```
syntax Σ-syntax A (λ x → B) = Σ[ x ∈ A ] B
```

So what we really need to construct is something of type `Σ ℚ λ x → x ≤ v`. Taking a look at the definition of `Σ`:

```
record Σ {a b} (A : Set a) (B : A → Set b) : Set (a ⊔ b) where
  constructor _,_
  field
    proj₁ : A
    proj₂ : B proj₁
```

It's a pair, constructed using `_,_`. The  first element is the number (a *witness*) and the second element is the proof that the first element satisfies the given proposition (`≤`). So, `thm` should look like this:

```
thm = ? , ?
```

We already know that the first element is a number (or, more precisely, something of type `ℚ`). So here we pick a suitable number - I picked `+ 1 ÷ 3`, which should hopefully be less than `+ 1 ÷ 2`.

```
thm = + 1 ÷ 3 , ?
```

This leaves us with the second question mark. There, we need something of type `+ 1 ÷ 3 ≤ v`. Again, we'll take a look at the definition of `≤`:

```
data _≤_ : ℚ → ℚ → Set where
  *≤* : ∀ {p q} →
        ℚ.numerator p ℤ.* ℚ.denominator q ℤ.≤
        ℚ.numerator q ℤ.* ℚ.denominator p →
        p ≤ q
```

Okay, this makes it easy: the only constructor is `*≤*` so we can't possibly pick the wrong one:

```
thm = + 1 ÷ 3 , *≤* ?
```

The `?` has now this type: `+ 2 ≤ + 3` (where `≤` comes from `Data.Integer`). Again, let's take a look at definition of `≤`:

```
data _≤_ : ℤ → ℤ → Set where
  -≤+ : ∀ {m n} → -[1+ m ] ≤ + n
  -≤- : ∀ {m n} → (n≤m : ℕ._≤_ n m) → -[1+ m ] ≤ -[1+ n ]
  +≤+ : ∀ {m n} → (m≤n : ℕ._≤_ m n) → + m ≤ + n
```

This gets slightly more interesting, as there are three possible constructors. However, taking a closer look, the only relevant one is `+≤+`, because the numbers on both sides are positive.

```
thm = + 1 ÷ 3 , *≤* (+≤+ ?)
```

The only thing that is left is to write a term of type `2 ≤ 3` (for `≤` from `Data.Nat`). I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

---

If the choice of constructor is unambiguous, you can use Agda's Emacs mode to do most of the work for you - you just keep pressing `C-c C-R` (refine) and Agda just writes the proof term for you.

---

I don't like writing silly proof terms like that, the computer should be more than able to write a proof of `x ≤ v` for me - after all, `≤` is *decidable*.

`Decidable` is defined in the standard library:

```
Decidable : ∀ {a b ℓ} {A : Set a} {B : Set b} → REL A B ℓ → Set _
Decidable _∼_ = ∀ x y → Dec (x ∼ y)

data Dec {p} (P : Set p) : Set p where
  yes : ( p :   P) → Dec P
  no  : (¬p : ¬ P) → Dec P
```

So, a binary relation `~` is decidable if you can write a binary function (let's call the arguments `x` and `y`), that returns either a proof of `x ~ y` or a refutation of `x ~ y` (that is `x ~ y → ⊥`).

Luckily for us, the proof of `≤`'s decidability is available in the standard library and can be found under the name `≤?` - I just need to write fairly simple machinery to extract the proof from there (if it exists):

```
open import Relation.Nullary

FromDec : ∀ {A : Set} → Dec A → Set
FromDec {A = A} (yes p) = A
FromDec         (no ¬p) = ⊤

fromDec : ∀ {A : Set} (d : Dec A) → FromDec d
fromDec (yes p) = p
fromDec (no ¬p) = _
```

`fromDec` extracts the proof from `Dec A`; if the proof is not there (i.e. the argument was `no ¬p` for some `¬p`), it just returns the empty tuple.

Now we can just let the computer figure out whether `+ 1 ÷ 3 ≤ v` holds or not. If it does - great, we just extract the computed proof with `fromDec` and we're done; if it doesn't, `fromDec` returns the empty tuple and we get a type error.

```
thm : Σ[ x ∈ ℚ ] x ≤ v
thm = , fromDec (+ 1 ÷ 3 ≤? v)
```

Comment: Would you please go over that last bit regarding getting the computer to do it for you. Otherwise great answer, but I got lost there. Thank-you :)

Comment: @Moses: Where exactly did you get lost?

Comment: The last section, "I don't like writing silly proof terms...". I'd really like to know how to not write silly proof terms and actually comprehend what's going on. Thanks!